# Что такое stack_underflow?

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!
Объясните пожалуйста что такое stack_underflow и когда он возникает на небольшом примере

Comment: Когда вы хотите снять что-то с пустого стека...

Comment: У стека есть push, и pop. Когда второго больше чем первого.

Comment: А как же есть класс исключений exception и в stdexception есть класс наследник exception с названием stack_underflow. Получается что подразумевается такая исключительная ситуация, которая может быть при работе со стеком, который выделяется под программу. А может ли произойти такое вообще? Когда такое может произойти?

Comment: Неужели программа захочет снимать что то с пустого стека?

Comment: По ошибке — да.